# How to update nested object that is type Map

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I wanted update nested object that is Map type Schema.
With the code below, it doesnt change anything. I tried to use set(),update(),finedOneAndUpdate(). but Any of them didn't work.
I really appreciate people help me.

Schema:

```
const ColumnSchema = new Schema(
  {
    title: { type: String },
    tasks: { type: Map, of: TaskSchema } <- I want to update this
    taskOrder: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: TaskSchema }] <- I want to update this
  }
);

const DashBoardSchema = new Schema(
  {
    user: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: User },
    dashBoardTitle: String,
    columns: { type: Map, of: ColumnSchema },
    columnOrder: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: ColumnSchema }]
  }
```

This is code I wrote for this

```
    let newTasks = {};
    let Board = await DashBoard.findOne({ _id: dashBoardId });
    let Column = await Board.columns.get(columnId);

    for (const key of Column.tasks.keys()) {
      // Prints "github", "twitter", "instagram"
      let item = Column.tasks.get(key);
      newTasks[item.id] = item;
    }

    // console.log("newTask", newTask);
    newTasks = {
      ...newTasks,
      [newTask._id]: newTask
    };

    const danshBoard = DashBoard.findOneAndUpdate(
      { _id: dashBoardId, columns: columnId },
      { $set: { tasks: newTasks }, $push: { taskOrder: newTask._id } },
      { new: true },
      (err, data) => {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        res.send(data);
      }
    );
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
```

Sample data here

```
enter code here
{
    "columnOrder": [
        "5e51860c45c55708cb441595"
    ],
    "_id": "5e51860c45c55708cb441596",
    "dashBoardTitle": "a",
    "columns": {
        "5e51860c45c55708cb441595": {
            "taskOrder": [],
            "_id": "5e51860c45c55708cb441595",
            "title": "Second column",
            "tasks": {}
        }
    },
    "__v": 0
}
```

Comment: Can you post sample data, it's not clear with Nodejs schema

Comment: @Valijon Thank you for your comment I added sample data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your query this way:

```
let updateCond = {};
updateCond["$set"] = {};
updateCond["$set"]["columns."+columnId +".tasks"] = newTasks;
updateCond["$push"] = {};
updateCond["$push"]["columns."+columnId +".taskOrder"] = newTask._id;

const danshBoard = DashBoard.findOneAndUpdate(
  { _id: dashBoardId },
  updateCond,
  { new: true },
  (err, data) => {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    res.send(data);
  }
);
```

**Btw:** If you had stored your data this way:

```
{
    "_id" : "5e51860c45c55708cb441596",
    "columnOrder" : [ 
        "5e51860c45c55708cb441595"
    ],
    "dashBoardTitle" : "a",
    "columns" : [ 
        {
            "id" : "5e51860c45c55708cb441595",
            "data" : {
                "taskOrder" : [],
                "_id" : "5e51860c45c55708cb441595",
                "title" : "Second column",
                "tasks" : {}
            }
        }
    ],
    "__v" : 0
}
```

We can apply MongoDB [arrayFilters](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#specify-arrayfilters-for-array-update-operations) feature

```
db.dashBoard.find({
  _id: "5e51860c45c55708cb441596"
},
{
  $set: {
    "columns.$[column].data.tasks": newTasks
  },
  $push: {
    "columns.$[column].data.taskOrder": newTask._id
  }
},
{
  new: true,
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "column.id": columnId
    }
  ]
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked perfectly. 
The part of ' updated ' is new for me. I appreciate how to study this technic. Is this technique mentioned in the mongoose doc?

Comment: @ShinCat Unfortunately, no. Mongoose is a framework to integrate with MongoDB (like Spring-data in Java). But, you can check native [MongoDB docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/method/db.collection.update/) about all new features